# /dev/vda1 is full but cannot find why

Tags: linux, jenkins, disk, diskspace

I have a server running Centos 7. This is the result of `df -h`

```
Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev                                 7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /dev
    tmpfs                                1.5G  139M  1.4G  10% /run
    /dev/vda1                             46G   44G     0 100% /
    tmpfs                                7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /dev/shm
    tmpfs                                7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    /dev/vda15                            99M  3.6M   95M   4% /boot/efi
    /dev/mapper/LVMVolGroup-DATA_VOLUME  138G   17G  114G  13% /mnt/data
    tmpfs                                1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /run/user/0
```

Even if there are 2GB of free space on `/` , it shows that the filesystem is at 100% of usage, and I can't install new packages because it tells me there's no space left on device. 
Besides, if I type `sudo du -sh /* | sort -rh | head -15`
the result is:

```
17G /mnt
1.1G    /usr
292M    /var
208M    /root
139M    /run
49M /boot
48M /tmp
32M /etc
28K /home
16K /lost+found
12K /anaconda-post.log
4.0K    /srv
4.0K    /opt
4.0K    /media
0   /sys
```

So it seems that there are no big files filling up the disk, and the sum of the sizes of the directories is not even equal to 44GB.

Additional info: the only service running on the server is Jenkins, but its home is under `/mnt/data/jenkins`.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You need to check what's currently using / (with `lsof` or `fuser`) and terminate it (or maybe you just need more space). Anyway it's not related to Jenkins, as it's mounted on another device.

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution. 
The problem was related to some deleted files kept open by Jenkins. 
Restarting the service the problem was solved.

Comment: Same here, I had a similar situation. In my case, it was an stuck process running that was filling the disk. Analyzing with `top` I've found a weird running process. I've killed and I've check the disk again `df -h` and the disk recovered completely.

Comment: In addition to the answer, you should also [set the Jenkins log size smaller](https://puvox.software/blog/solution-clean-full-disk-space-by-dev-vda1/).

Answer (score 2):

The problem was related to the system cache/temp storage. Linux system created the cache files and its archive from time to time, especially when some long option is run like DB import or crone job etc..  or sometimes server up from sines long.

> Restarting the service or server

so due to that, the cache/ temp files were deleted and the problem was solved.

even in windows, we faced that kind of performance issue when RAM is low, and restarting the system is the primary solution for that.

Comment: Please be more descriptive with your answers.

Comment: THIS. I've looked into a lot of possible solutions but nothing worked. I just restarted my server and it lowered from 100% to about 24%.